Is there a way to test an OS update before installing it
I have 22.04.4LTS installed on a server PC that I have running a few programs such as plex and *arr apps and such. I have the popup to upgrade to 24.04.1LTS but I don't want to just install it straight away. Is there a way I can test the update somehow, without it being installed to make sure everything works with the update?

Once you have learned how to test, consider helping to test during the pre-release months, and reporting the bugs you discover. That's the time when bug reports get the most developer attention. Ubuntu's testing and bug reporting is done by volunteers. An unreliable upgrade = Too few testing volunteers during pre-release.

You can clone your system, then play it back into a virtual machine. If your system has /home on a different partition this is especially handy because you don't have to copy all your data. Just the small / partition, and have a minimal /home.
Once set up, you can quickly test updates by snapshotting the VM and running the update. If it breaks the system, restore the snapshot.
I have these testing VMs of all my important systems. But I don't test every update, only the scary ones.

"You can clone your system" It would be nice to explain how do do it, or provide a link with instructions.

@A.L I'm just describing the general process here. Many people will not be interested because it's a lot of overhead. There are several ways to clone a system.

Generally, it is a good idea to have a second drive for the operating system for backup / restore purposes.
If you have or get such a second drive, you can clone your system or make an image of the whole drive using Clonezilla. This makes it very convenient to replace the system if there is a crash (hardware or software failure).
That second drive can be used to store the original system when you test do-release-upgrade from 22.04.x to 24.04.y.

Do a backup or clone first, just in case.
If using LVM and / and /boot is in same LV (I'm now using such partitoning), and the VG has free space(My VG is 334G and ubuntu/root LV is 300G, so I have 34G free). Then you can use LVM's snapshot feature.
My partitioning is below, you can ignore p2-p4(windows) and p6(incus zfs storage):
$ lsblk /dev/nvme0n1
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1         259:0    0 476,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0   125G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4     259:4    0     2G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p5     259:5    0 334,8G  0 part 
│ └─ubuntu-root 252:0    0   300G  0 lvm  /
└─nvme0n1p6     259:6    0  14,9G  0 part 
$ sudo vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree 
  ubuntu   1   1   0 wz--n- 334,81g 34,81g
$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log  Cpy%Sync Convert
  root ubuntu -wi-ao---- 300,00g                                                    

before do-release-upgrade, do a snapshot
sudo lvcreate --extents 100%FREE --snapshot --name root_snap /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root

Yes, I just leave 34G free intentionally for system upgrade try, it is enough for a release upgrade, it is just used to store what you've change to your system. If you don't have free space, you can shrink your file system(xfs is hard, I use ext4), then shrink your LV to make space. This is a different topic.
You can upgrade you system now.
If you are satisfied with the upgrade, you can just remove the snapshot
sudo lvremove ubuntu/root_snap

You might hit the problem that the snapshot is in used, and cannot be deleted, like this, I'm stuck on this for some time too. The solution is easy, just kill the process which is using the snapshot.
If upgrade is not good, you can roll back all the changes by:
sudo lvconvert --merge ubuntu/root_snap
sudo reboot

If your system cannot boot into system, you have to use a Live USB or so.
I use this method to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 before, and this month from 22.04 to 24.04. Maybe lucky, never ever do a roll back.
I think those file systems with snapshot feature - such as btrfs, zfs - could achieve similar thing, but I don't have a chance to try it.
This page is what I refer to, when I do upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 at Aug 30, and remove the snapshot at Sep 8, after a week of try.
